# How to I start the site with QueryString?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy, mako

I have the Server's programmed in Cherrypy and using Mako.

I haved one variable (json_data where is the content of a file [json]) that contain the data for work on my site.

To change these parameters, I have to use the query string

To simplify my work on data management.

I need to have my variable (json_data) on my server url when it is open.

(`localhost:8100?=json_data?json_data=demo_title%24+Demo+title+%23+`)
I know to replace the separator's python to javascript.

**I want the variable json_data on adding on the url when I starting the my site but how?**

Info:

Json_data=

```
demo_title%24+Demo+title+%23+proc1_script%24+script.sh+parameters+%23+proc1_chk_make%24+on+%23+outputp2_value%24++%23+demo_input_description%24+hola+mundo+%23+outputp4_visible%24+on+%23+outputp4_info%24++%23+inputdata1_max_pixels%24+1024000+%23+tag%24++%23+outputp1_id%24+nanana+%23+proc1_src_compresion%24+zip+%23+proc1_chk_cmake%24+off+%23+outputp3_description%24++%23+outputp3_value%24++%23+inputdata1_description%24+input+data+description+%23+inputp2_description%24+bien%3F+%23+inputp3_description%24+funciona+%23+proc1_cmake%24+D+CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3Astring%3DRelease++%23+outputp2_visible%24+on+%23+outputp3_visible%24+on+%23+outputp1_type%24+header+%23+inputp1_type%24+text+%23+demo_params_description%24+va+bien+%23+outputp1_description%24++%23+inputdata1_type%24+image2d
```

Update with program

```
import cherrypy
import urllib
#import requests

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        jsondict = [('foo', '1'), ('foo', '2')]
        p = urllib.urlencode(jsondict)
        #url = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8080?%s" % params)
        #urlVar = 1
        #urlVar2 = 2
        #requests.get("localhost:8080/?", params =p)
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("localhost:8080?" + params)


cherrypy.config.update({

        'server.socketPort': 8080

})
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: Look at cherrypy.url. It has a query string variable which might work for you. http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/cherrypy.html

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask, why do you need to do this? Couldn't these variables be defaults for the method processing the request?

Comment: Yes and no. It's not a direct answer to his question but is an option if his approach doesn't need to be the way he describes.

Comment: raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("localhost:8080?" + params)
With this, I do a redirect and I have.

Comment: import cherrypy
import urllib
#import requests

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        jsondict = [('foo', '1'), ('foo', '2')]
        p = urllib.urlencode(jsondict)
        #url = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8080?%s" % params)
        #urlVar = 1
        #urlVar2 = 2
        #requests.get("localhost:8080/?", params =p)
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("localhost:8080?" + params)
        

cherrypy.config.update({
    
        'server.socketPort': 8080
    
})
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())

Comment: urllib.urlopen("localhost:8080?%s"; % params        You have ;  before % params. That should be there. This is preventing the params from being added to your string